# send dropzone data as POST along with other inputs - laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, dropzone.js

I have general form and I need to include dropzone to upload multiple image along with other inputs. I have dropzone.js and dropzone.css files from dropzone site and has included the path in view file. But I am not able to send files in dropzone to controller for saving as post. All other inputs are being submitted as request but not the files in dropzone.

My form is like:

```
 <form method="post" action=" 
  {{route('property.save')}}" enctype="multipart/form- 
  data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
 <...other input fields...>
<div id="myDropZone" class="dropzone dropzone-design">
<div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to 
 upload</span></div>
 </div>
<button  name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
```

I have checked if the file is passed or not as:

```
 if ($request->hasFile('file')){
        return "true";
    }else{
        return "false";
    }
```

It returns false. I have also edited dropzone.js file as per tutorials in net but could not find success so im finally posting this problem here.

Comment: You may have send the file already, before you submit. Use a webdeveloper helper for your browser, see what you send when dropping a pic. In my case, the $request->get('file') is a filename or an array of filenames.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey how do i make dropzone send file only when submit button is pressed along other inputs?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.It's the whole point of dropzone: async uploading files. Personally I have opted for https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload in other parts of the site (to create photo albums). It's not hard to implement and looks really nice. It shows a preview of the dropped files before uploading. Careful you don't upload them all at once. You may clog your the production server. Happened to me.